# Combine variable with variable and text in Python

Tags: python

I wondering what i am doing wrong here..
The issue is this line *final = 'PAT_' SID '.txt'*
where SID is a variable
Can anybody have a quick look, I am sure I am doing something stupid.

### Below is the complete code...

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
global SID
global final
with open ('sampleID.txt', 'r') as inF:
    for line in inF:
        if 'Sample ID:' in line:

           SID = line.split(':')[1]
           final = 'PAT_' SID '.txt'
           os.rename("sampleID.txt",final)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate your question to include the exact error you are getting?

Answer (score 3):

To concatenate variables, you need to add (`+`) them:

```
final = 'PAT_' + SID + '.txt'
```

You can also use the built-in function [`str.format()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) here:

```
final = 'PAT_ {} .txt'.format(SID)
```

Or even the old way of string formatting, which is still compatible in Python 3 (but `str.format` is much better to use):

```
final = 'PAT_ %s .txt' % SID
```

---

By the way, your global statements aren't needed. A `with` statement does not introduce a new scope, hence everything defined in a with statement is a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

use `+` to concat strings in python